# Alternate Get Listview Items Count VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I tried

```
For i = 0 To Data.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
```

That works, but i don't want **looping**, so what is the alternate code for that?

Comment: What is your question? Do you cant to execute an action for x-ampunt of times? Or do you want to know how many items there are inside a ListView? Are you using web controls, windows form controls or WPF, or another technology?

Comment: For replace text

 `For i = 0 To Data.ListView2.Items.Count - 1

            ReplaceALL(Data.ListView2.Items(i).Text, Data.ListView2.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text, Me.RichTextBox1)

        Next`

Comment: You'll always have to loop through the elements if you want to change the text.

Comment: I want replace text in RichTextBox from Listview data
RicthTextbox.text = "test 1"

i want change with Listview data, i have 2 listview

Listview 1 item contain is "test" and the subitem is "1", the result of richtextbox now from = "test 1" to = "1 1" because Listview item, but i want add item again with inverted but the result in richtextbox not = "1 test" but "test test" :(

Comment: Please rephrase your questions, and add additional screenshots, because I have no clue what you mean :/